# isSorted function in Javascript: How to use for-of-loop in the code

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JS writing code, and I have a question about the isSorted function.

I am supposed to use for-of-loop in the code.

**Here is the task:**

Declare a function isSorted.

```
/**
 * @param {Array<number>} ??? - an array of numbers
 * @returns {boolean} whether or not the given array is sorted
 */
```

**Here is what i wrote**

```
function isSorted(array) {
  const result = [];
  for (const number of array) {
    if (number < number1 && number2 ) {
      result.push(number);
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Here is the error message that I get**

[image: error message]

**Here is the test that I could not pass with my code above**

```
actual = isSorted([1, 2, 3]);
expected = true;

if (actual === expected) {
  console.log("Test PASSED.");
} else {
  console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
  console.group("Result:");
  console.log("  actual:", actual);
  console.log("expected:", expected);
  console.groupEnd();
}

actual = isSorted([3, 2, 3]);
expected = false;

if (actual === expected) {
  console.log("Test PASSED.");
} else {
  console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
  console.group("Result:");
  console.log("  actual:", actual);
  console.log("expected:", expected);
  console.groupEnd();
}
```

Comment: A couple things - the error you're getting is saying that "number1" is undefined, i.e. it hasn't been declared.  In your isSorted function, you reference two variables that haven't been created yet - number1 and number2.

The other thing is that your for...of loop will never run more than one time, because you return true in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: I can't understand the logic behind your isSorted function... It takes the first element of the array, compare it with two undefined variables and then return true?!?

Comment: @Clark Thank you for the pointer. Can you teach me what I actually need to write in the code to pass the test? 

Sorry, I am totally blanking here, too hard for me as a beginner.

Comment: Check each value, and if it is smaller than the previous one, return false. If you get to the end, return true.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the i-th element of the array with the next one. If one element is greater than the following the array is not sorted

```
function isSorted(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if (array[i + 1]) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or you can reduce your array to a boolean value (see [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)):

```
function isSorted(array) {
    return array.reduce((prev, cur) => prev !== false && cur >= prev && cur)
}
```

where `prev` is the the value resulting from the previous iteration and `cur` the current iteration item.

Comment: Thank you @jbrond!

However I get this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: arr is not defined at isSorted

Any other hint, please?

Comment: @jessieWJ Read the error message. `arr` is not defined. jbrond most likely made a typo. `arr` should be `array`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thank you, that was it (it works now)!

Answer (score 0):

Try this isSorted function:

```
function isSorted(array) {
  let previousNo = null;
  for (const number of array) {
    if (previousNo != null && number < previousNo) {
      return false;
    }
    previousNo = number;
  }
  return true;
}
```

It still uses the for..of loop, and here's what it's doing:

- "previousNo" will store the number that had been looked at during the previous iteration of the loop, so we can see if our current number is less than it.  if it is, that means that the numbers are not stored in ascending order, i.e., it isn't sorted (so we return false in this case).
- If no problems were found in the loop, we return true instead (your version did this as well, the only difference is, you returned true inside the loop, preventing the other items from being checked).

Answer (score 0):

This fuction compare array members: first with second, second with third...etc. If the following member of the array is less than the actual, return false(array is not sorted).

```
function isSorted(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
        return false;
      } 
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some commentary about why this is suggested

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: This fuction compare array members:  first with second, second with third...etc. If the following member of the array is less than the actual, return false(array is not sorted).